# How can I improve the layout of returned list into [a = 0, b = 0, ...]?

Tags: python-3.x

#### Summary:

The function below counts the letters in a string and puts them in a list and returns the list.

#### Problem:

The list that is returned by the function below doesn't look very elegant.

```
string = "Hello, world!"
lijst = []
string = string.lower()

def countAlphabeth( string ):
    for i in range( 0, 26 ):
        x = chr(ord( "a" ) + i )
        string.count( x )
        lijst.append( str( x + ' =' ) )
        lijst.append(string.count( x ) )
    return lijst

lijst = countAlphabeth( string )
print( lijst )
```

This is how the list appears after print:

```
['a =', 0, 'b =', 0, 'c =', 0, 'd =', 1, 'e =', 1, 'f =', 0, 'g =', 0, 'h =', 
  1, 'i =', 0, 'j =', 0, 'k =', 0, 'l =', 3, 'm =', 0, 'n =', 0, 'o =', 2, 
 'p =', 0, 'q =', 0, 'r =', 1, 's =', 0, 't =', 0, 'u =', 0, 'v =', 0, 'w =', 
  1, 'x =', 0, 'y =', 0, 'z =',0]
```

#### Desired result:

What change should I make to get the desired result to look something like this below?

```
[a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1, e = 1, f = 0, g = 0, h = 1, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0,
 l = 3, m = 0, n = 0, o = 2, p = 0, q = 0, r = 1, s = 0, t = 0, u = 0, v = 0,
 w = 1, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

def print_count(s : str):
    c = Counter(s.lower())
    for letter in ascii_lowercase:
        print('{} = {}'.format(letter, c[letter]))

print_count('Hello, world!')
```

prints

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 1
e = 1
f = 0
g = 0
h = 1
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
l = 3
m = 0
n = 0
o = 2
p = 0
q = 0
r = 1
s = 0
t = 0
u = 0
v = 0
w = 1
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Same as I wrote to your fellow helpen MatrixMan above, this is also a very nice solution. Yet still above my level of expertise, hopefully this will change soon.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a list in kind of a strange way.  What you really want is a dictionary.  I'd do something like this:

```
class Freq:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.dijct = {}
        for i in range( 0, 26 ):
            x = chr(ord( "a" ) + i )
            string.count( x )
            self.dijct[x] = string.count(x)

    def __str__(self):
        printString = "["

        for (letter, frequency) in self.dijct.items():
            printString += "{} = {}, ".format(letter, frequency)

        printString = printString[:-2] # remove trailing comma and space
        printString += "]"
        return printString

string = "Hello, world!"
string = string.lower()

print(Freq(string))
```

Output:

```
[a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1, e = 1, f = 0, g = 0, h = 1, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 3, m = 0, n = 0, o = 2, p = 0, q = 0, r = 1, s = 0, t = 0, u = 0, v = 0, w = 1, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, ]
```

It might be possible to write your own `__str__` function and trick python's list class into using it, but I think you're much better off just providing your own class to store the frequency distribution, that way you can provide your own print function in a straightforward way.

Comment: Thanks! although this is still above my experience level, since I just started to learn Python, I do appreciate your solution, it works perfectly.

Comment: Sure thing. At the very least you should learn to use dictionaries, they'll make your life easier:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-dictionaries-in-python-3 Other things to search for: "classes" "functions" and "\_\_str\_\_".   If you're ever uncertain about how something works just go back and forth between some documentation and an interactive shell. You can tinker your way to understanding pretty easily with a bit of focus.

Comment: Thanks! For your uplifting words as well! You have been a great help! I believe dictionaries are being discussed in the next chapter of my book :-) I will have a look at the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter. Note down the list of your desired value.

```
from collections import Counter

def data_list(str_data):
    lst = list()
    if not isinstance(str_data, str):
        return lst
    resp = Counter(str_data.lower())
    for ascii in range(97, 123):
        letter = chr(ascii)
        lst.append('{} = {}'.format(letter, resp.get(letter, 0)))
    return lst

print(data_list('Hello, world!'))
```

Output:

```
['a = 0', 'b = 0', 'c = 0', 'd = 1', 'e = 1', 'f = 0', 'g = 0', 'h = 1', 'i = 0', 'j = 0', 'k = 0', 'l = 3', 'm = 0', 'n = 0', 'o = 2', 'p = 0', 'q = 0', 'r = 1', 's = 0', 't = 0', 'u = 0', 'v = 0', 'w = 1', 'x = 0', 'y = 0', 'z = 0']
```

Comment: Also a creative solution, unfortunately still above my level of expertise as well.